# How to insert into table when particular condition not satisfied

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to insert into table `shp_postmeta`when it does not have the `meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'`.

The inserted value is from the same table `shp_postmeta` where `meta_key = '_product_image_gallery'` i.e. in form of sql statement

```
SELECT meta_key, meta_value FROM shp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_product_image_gallery'
```

This table is related to a different table `shp_post` where `shp_posts.ID = shp_postmeta.post_id`

The table structure of `shp_postmeta` is:

```
meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value
```

Table structure of `shp_posts` table is:

```
ID | post_author | ....
```

These are WordPress table structure.

**EDIT 1**

In WP there are some woocommerce product which does not have featured image but they have product gallery images. Images are uploaded into the media.So I wanted to make the gallery image to featured image to which products those do not have featured image. Products are in large amount. So I wanted to automate it through script.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it? It would make the question much clearer.

Comment: See edit it may help to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because shp_postmeta has an auto_increment PK you can execute:

```
INSERT INTO shp_postmeta 
  SELECT null, p1.post_id, '_thumbnail_id', p1.meta_value 
  FROM shp_postmeta p1
  WHERE p1.post_id NOT IN(
             SELECT p2.post_id 
             FROM shp_postmeta p2 
             WHERE p2.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id')
     AND p1.meta_key = '_product_image_gallery' ;
```

Comment: it has syntax error. May be null not required in 2nd line.

Comment: You must set to null first field, the auto_increment PK.

Comment: I just replaced the null to '' and its worked thanks.

Comment: It's weird, but I test it only with MySQL 5.7.14 and WordPress 4.0.10

Comment: I have tested it in phpmyadmin, but don't know the version